# Codeigniter - How to set name property from database

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have 2 questions:

1. How do I call result from model to name property in any form inputs?
2. How do I get the dynamic name property posted in Controller?

This is what I tried in my HTML:

```php
<input type="text" name="saa_<?php echo $row1['Tube_No']; ?>" value="<?= $row1['Pin_No']; ?>">
```

And this is what I tried in my controller:

```php
$data = array(
    'SA_No' => $this->input->post('saa_.$row1'),            
);
```

How do i get my form input name property get posted to controller.

Comment: If you wanted know the input name and value of this input then, Use print_r($_POST) . Only this one i can understand from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the value of `$row1['Tube_No']`

```
$valueDefinedWhenRenderingTheView = $row1['Tube_No'];
```

then you need to access it like this:

```
$data = array(
    'SA_No' => $this->input->post('saa_' . $valueDefinedWhenRenderingTheView)
);
```

because, when your defining the input name to be the concatenation of "saa_" and the value of `$row1['Tube_No']`.